# Saturn Router - same function for getf and get?

Tags: f#, saturn-framework

should be simple question but I can't find the API docs that detail how to do this.

I have a controller function like this

```
let loadScreen (ctx: HttpContext) (number: int) : HttpHandler = htmlString "etc"
```

And a router that defines two routes that use that function. One passes a default value of 0 to the `number` parameter. The other allows a user to specify a number

```
let PageRouter = router {
    (* Works fine: *)
    get "/order" (warbler (fun (_, ctx) -> PageController.loadScreen ctx 0))
    (* Does not compile: *) 
    getf "/order/%i" (fun number func ctx -> PageController.loadScreen ctx number)
}
```

That gives the error

```
This expression was expected to have type 'HttpFuncResult' but here has type 'HttpFunc -> 'a -> HttpFuncResult'
```

I know it's a simple missing thing but can't figure out what.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` combinator expects a second parameter of type `HttpHandler`. This is it in your code:

```
get "/order" (warbler (fun (_, ctx) -> PageController.loadScreen ctx 0))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                         /
                                This is an HttpHandler value
```

`getf`, on the other hand, expects a different second parameter. It expects a function that takes an `int` as a parameter and *returns* a `HttpHandler` as a result.

So just stick `fun number ->`  in front of your existing `HttpHandler`, and voila:

```
getf "/order/%i" (fun number -> 
  (warbler (fun (_, ctx) -> PageController.loadScreen ctx number))
)
```